# Apply OR condition on nested and condition

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm trying to understand how [OR] condition will work on nested and condition.

Below is my sample query

```
select * from t1 as a join t2 as b  on a.id=b.id
where (a.value > 110 and a.value <= 120)
  OR
     (a.value > 120 and b.age > 20 and b.status='A')
```

Will the above statement applies OR condition on the complete first (a.value > 110 and a.value <= 120)  and second (a.value > 120 and b.age > 20 and b.status='A') or will it apply OR condition on a.value <= 120 and a.value > 120

Can someone please help understand, since i'm new to sql it is bit confusing???

Appreciate your time and help :-)

Thanks in advance

Comment: This case is not sql specific or any other programming language: since you enclose each statement in parentheses and combine them with the OR operator, then yes OR will be applied to the results of each parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

the query will return data from either of the inside baracket complex condition s true

```
    let say c1= (a.value > 110 and a.value <= 120) 
    Or 
    c2=(a.value > 120 and b.age > 20 and b.status='A')
```

so if c1 or c2 is true query will be retured data but query will not be returned data if both c1 and c1 is false

Answer (score 0):

If you use parentheses the answer is clear, as first the content of teh parentheses is evaluated than the `OR` between them.

As in the [Oracle Condition Precendence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions001.htm#i1034834) the `AND` is ordered *before* `OR` you may even remove the parentheses to get the same effect - see example below (simplified to focus on the point).

```
with cnt as (
select rownum id from dual connect by level <= 10)
select * from cnt where
(id > 3 and id <= 5) or (id >= 7 and id < 10);

        ID
----------
         4
         5
         7
         8
         9

with cnt as (
select rownum id from dual connect by level <= 10)
select * from cnt where
id > 3 and id <= 5 or id >= 7 and id < 10;         

        ID
----------
         4
         5
         7
         8
         9
```

Parentheses are required, if you want to priorize `OR` over the `AND` such as in example below

```
(id < 3 or id < 7) and id > 1
```

If you remove the parentheses you get the result from this predicate:

```
id < 3 or (id < 7 and id > 1)
```

*HTH*

Comment: Thanks alot Marmite Bomber for clarifying this :-) .